# Adding channels with random delays in ns3/ndnsim

Tags: networking, random, delay, ns-3, ndnsim

I am working on simulation scenarios using ns3/ndnsim, l've already done some using point to point channels between nodes which use constant delays. I would like to add randomness to these delays (say normal distribution).

I've worked on omnet++ which presents this functionality and can be used so easily.

My question, is there any way to do this on ns3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of delays relevant here: transmission delay and propagation delay.

Transmission delay is a function is the size of the frame, and the data rate of the medium. For a given link, the data rate is typically constant.

Propagation delay is a function of the type of medium. For a wired medium, propagation delay is typically constant. Non-uniform propagation delays are associated with wireless mediums.

So, effectively, you want a random propagation delay. *ns-3* does have a [RandomPropagationDelayModel](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_random_propagation_delay_model.html), but it's only used by wireless mediums, so you're out of luck.